# Git empty response from server over https vpn after upgrade to sierra

Tags: git, macos, ssl, macos-sierra, openconnect

I've been facing this weird issue ever since i upgraded osx to Sierra,
all pulls/push fail with the following error for a remote repo over client vpn (Theres a VPN + firewall over browser).Its been failing for everyone who has updated to osx sierra on my team and works for people who are still on El Capitan...

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOS=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git pull origin master
16:52:02.657710 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'pull' 'origin' 'master'
16:52:02.660782 run-command.c:336       trace: run_command: 'fetch' '--update-head-ok' 'origin' 'master'
16:52:02.661465 exec_cmd.c:120          trace: exec: 'git' 'fetch' '--update-head-ok' 'origin' 'master'
16:52:02.665573 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'fetch' '--update-head-ok' 'origin' 'master'
16:52:02.671371 run-command.c:336       trace: run_command: 'git-remote-https' 'origin' 'https://<URL>/repo.git'
fatal: unable to access 'https://<URL>/repo.git': Empty reply from server
```

My git config looks like below-:

```
http.sslverify=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
```

The repo is hosted on a gitlab server,i've already updated git and everything else to the latest version.One more thing i've noticed is that accessing the gitlab repo over chrome seems to work but not over Safari(It takes a long long time and sometimes fails).

I'd like some help trying to debug whats happening?Is there any more level of logging i can get to see what headers are going and what the response is?

Comment: MacOS firewall active?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - Nope, deactivated...narrowed it down though,seems to be a problem with OpenSSL, the newer version on Sierra doesnt work with certificates with older ciphers for some reason